# Uploading custom files, using CKFinder

Tags: java, file-extension, ckfinder

I installed Java CKFinder & CKEditor and it works well what means that I can  upload images. But I must give users the ability to upload pdf-s to the same library as the %BASE_DIR%. 
When I try to do it through the image button uploading form, it says: "Invalid file extension.".

Comment: Could you post you `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Please get familiar with Resource Types: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Configuration/Resource_Types

By default there are three types of resource types: Files, Images and Flash. Each resource types has a set of files extensions it accepts. **The pdf files are defined as in File resource type.**

**How to access appropriate resource type from CKEditor level?** By default the flash resource type is can be accessed from Flash dialog, the image resource type from Image dialog and file resource type from Link dialog.

You can always change this behaviour by experimenting with Manual Integration method http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration#Manual_Integration. I would however leave it as it is, at least at the beginning. IMHO default behaviour makes a lot of sense as you manage images from Image dialog, flash from Flash dialog and Files from Link dialog (in 99,9% cases you just want to link the file). If you would like to make link to file being represented by the image, you can use http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl e.g.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',     
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder.html?Type=Images',                 
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : '../ckfinder.html?Type=Flash',
    filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl : '../ckfinder.html',     
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/CKFinderJava/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Files', //CKFinderJava is main application folder in my case
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/CKFinderJava/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?type=Images&command=QuickUpload'
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '/CKFinderJava/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?type=Flash&command=QuickUpload'
} );
```